# Trying to run multiple instances of VLC

Tags: multiple-monitors, vlc, video-player, multiple-instances

I'm a total noob at Linux (but I'm learning).
I am trying to run a video presentation - but I need it to run THREE separate Mpeg or AVI videos at precisely the same time and in sync.

I read http://www.videolan.org/doc/play-howto/en/ch04.html which shows how to address each of the three monitors with each instance of VLC.|

The WALL feature seems cool, but I'm using 3 monitors for video output and one for a control panel (please excuse the Windows entomology).

The option:
--vout  allows you to select the video output module.
seems to be the way to address each video output separately (PLEASE correct me if I'm wrong about this)

So what I'm asking is basically this: If I want to run three separate videos, to three separate monitors using ubuntu and VLC, how can I run all three at exactly the same time, and is there a way to get them to sync? (MIDI, smpte time code, etc?)

I need just one channel of either mono or stereo audio to run from (let's say) the first video file.

Any and all input would be VERY welcome. (But please keep in mind, I'm rather new at linux, so please have patience with me)

Thanks in Advance,
Rik

Comment: let me share exactly what im trying to do. this is for a rock band on-stage video presentation. the audio is only going to feed from one (say, video1.mpg) as a cowbell click track that only the drummer hears. so, when the drummer signals that he's ready, the person at the computer console runs the script and three monitors

Comment: (actually, LCD video walls) run three separate videos - one to each screen. its imperative that they run no more than a half second out of sync. i saw on vlc's tech site that there's a relative easy way to shoot each instance to a separate display device - but the real trick (i think) is to find some utility that can take a script - parse the three lines of code, and execute all three lines at exactly the same time.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have multiple monitors so I can't help you there. As far as opening 3 videos at the same time the closest I can suggest would be using "&" to open the files sequentially. They won't be in sync, but because they are opened 1 after the other very quickly they will be very very close to in sync, most likely resulting in a slight echo like sound. Of course this assumes the video file aren't ones that strain the system and that they are stored on a storage device capable of feeding the data rate of 3 videos at once. If not the out-of-sync gap between players will be more apparent. For example I tested this with 2 1080p 70mb mp4 files in a virtual machine, and they were almost in sync, a slight echo was the only indication they weren't. However when I attempted 3 the gap became larger because it was a 1080p video running 3 instanced in a vm, and vms don't get good performance. Keep in mind that this will only help you open the file, it not give you control over where the video's appear on your desktop screen. I believe the default is they layer instances over each other.

Example (assumes video file is called "example" and is located in your user accounts download folder):

"vlc /home/username/Downloads/example.mp4 & vlc /home/username/Downloads/example2.mp4 & vlc /home/username/Downloads/example3.mp4"

Answer (score 0):

Here one way but you can more advance with this, create a shell script doing this:

1. Launch VLC instance through command line, save their PID's.
2. Use `wmctrl` to get WID for each VLC windows and save them.
3. Use `wmctrl` to displace the window or even use `xdotool` to send the required keys for that like a macro.
4. Use `xdotool` to send key signal for each instance window to play on same time, difference should be in milliseconds. `xdotool` can send it in a single command.

You can go far using [Media Player Remote Interfacing Specification (MPRIS)](http://Media%20Player%20Remote%20Interfacing%20Specification%20(MPRIS)) or keep it simple by doing some steps manually. Keeping time/benefit in balance.